# Getting "curl: (58) unable to use client certificate" with calls using p12 file

Tags: ssl, curl, p12

I created a p12 file on my MacOS ElCaptain, using a `.pem` and `.key` file via openssl command :

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in <PEM_file>.pem -inkey <PRIVATE_KEY>.key -out <FILENAME>.p12
```

Everything went ok. I was able to make my cURL calls using this p12.

When I did the same on my Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (with the same `.pem` and `.key`), I started to receive this message when I used cURL with the p12:

```
curl: (58) unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`curl` supports about a dozen different SSL/TLS implementations and how certs&keys are supplied varies depending on which implementation is used in your build. Use `curl -V` (upper vee) to check. I'd guess, but don't know, the MacOS build uses SecureTransport; the (standard) package on my off-in-the-corner Ubuntu 14.04.4 definitely uses OpenSSL.

Per the man page and confirmed by experiment **on my Ubuntu**, this build **wants PEM format files**, not PKCS12. These are the same two files you used as *input* to `openssl pkcs12 -export`, or you can concatenate them and just use that for `--cert` (this can work because PEM format marks each block separately); and if you don't have them anymore you can just use `openssl pkcs12 -in foo.p12 -out foo.pem` (i.e. OMIT `-export`) to convert back.

Comment: Thank you, you save our day.. ;-)

Comment: In my case I needed also to update curl to a version upper of 7.29